# Fragment inside ViewPager not getting refreshed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

**This is the Fragment in which i am capturing Image using camera2basic(google sample).**

[image]

**And this method i am using to update the gallery with the latest captured image:**

```
private void refreshGallery(File file)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

**And this is the Gallery Fragment where i am showing all the images stored in SD Card:**

[image]

**Here MainActivity is having a ViewPager, which is having 5 Fragments**:

- FragmentHome
- FragmentGallery
- FragmentCamera
- FragmentStar
- FragmentProfile

**and inside FragmentGallery, there is an another ViewPager(GalleryViewPager) which is having 2 Fragments**:

- FragmentPhotos
- FragmentVideos

**Now as you can see, the CameraFragment is in a ViewPager of MainActivity, and the FragmentPhotos(which is showing all the photos of the gallery) is in another ViewPager inside FragmentGallery.
Now when i click the photo and navigate to FragmentPhotos(inside FragmentGallery), the gallery gets updated and recently clicked pic is shown(only for first time) but as i click more pics and return to FragmentPhotos(inside FragmentGallery) *the gallery doesn't gets updated* !!! Also when I move to a different tab(other than Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3 ie Tab4 or Tab5) ie when the ViewPager gets detroyed, then the gallery gets updated every time without any problem !!!
Please help me, how to update the fragment inside ViewPager.
Although I tried to update it with notifysetchanged but it had no effect.**

To initiate the Gallery i am calling the initGallery() from MainActivity on Tab Selection(when the selected tab is the Gallery Fragment), as:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerGallery);
                    GalleryViewPagerAdapter adapter = (GalleryViewPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        Fragment fragmentObject = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, i);
                        if (fragmentObject instanceof FragmentPhotos) {
                            FragmentPhotos fragment = (FragmentPhotos) fragmentObject;
                            if (fragment != null) {
                                ((FragmentPhotos) fragment).initGallery();
                                Log.e("", "Gallery called");
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

and the following is my PagerAdpater:

```
public class GalleryViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    int numOfTabs;

    public GalleryViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

**Following is initGallery():**

```
public void initGallery()
    {
        {
            new GetImagesFromCard().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }
```

**and GetImagesFromCard is as follows:**

```
private class GetImagesFromCard extends AsyncTask<Void,LoadedImage,Void>
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ArrayList<LoadedImage> bitmapArrays=new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN};
            String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy);
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int size = cursor.getCount();
            if (size==0)
            {

            }
            int imageId =0;
            int i=0;
            while (i<size && !isCancelled())
            {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                imageId = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageId);
                publishProgress(new LoadedImage(uri.toString()));
                if (i==0)
                {
                    new ShowImagesEnlarged(i).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                }
                i++;
            }
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(LoadedImage... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            for (LoadedImage photo: values)
            {
                imageAdapter.addPhoto(photo);
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                bitmapArrays.add(photo);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Log.e("","Task Cancelled");
            super.onCancelled();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show some code please, I assume you do not refresh the gallery fragments content after you made a photo. The first time the gallery fragment is created it loads all information from gallery, after that the fragment you see is the cached one within the adapter... So please provide code from fragment instantiation and the viewpagers adapter...

Comment: Now can u help me @David

Answer (score 1):

write this line where you extend FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatPagerAdapter

```
       @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
```

it will automatically refresh fragment when you swipe one fragment to another in your viewPager or else you can attach and detach fragment like this

This will refresh current fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

note: You have to put this code in a one-time event like when data is refreshed otherwise your app will be hang too much.. just dont write in onCreat and onCreatView method

Comment: This will work, but in my experience it is more efficient to do something like creating an interface for content refreshable fragments an put them into the adapter, when something have to be refreshed you could call updateContent() directly and maybe just refresh the gallery list adapters content, so the fragment does not have to be recreated.

Comment: well choice is yours..  u asked question so i just gave you a solution that what i think is good.. happy coding..

Comment: I have already put the getItemPosition in FragmentStatePagerAdapter, but  its not working!

Comment: use FragmentPagerAdapter instead. maybe work.. bcz i also face the same problem and its work for me..

Comment: Did u use both getItemPosition and FragmentTransaction at the same time ?

Comment: no.. i just use getItemPosition method with FragmentPagerAdapter, but first i apply attach and detach method its work fine but in my case there is no single event that i can set this method, so its hang my mobile.. so for me getItemPosition is the best solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118313/discussion-between-mayur-saini-and-sagar-chavada).

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I would suggest is that you create an interface like this:

```
public interface IContentRefreshableFragment {
    void refreshContent()
}
```

All of your Fragments should implement this interface e.g.:

```
public class FragmentPhoto implements IContentRefreshableFragment {
    @Override
    public void refreshContent() {
        // You have to refresh your dataset here and push it into your
        // adapter, don't forget to call adapter.notifiyDataSetChanged();
        initGallery();
    }
}
```

Then you start your Intent for taking a photo with an ResultCode:

```
public static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "PHOTO_TAKEN";    
startActivityForResult(PhotoActivity.class, PHOTO_TAKEN);
```

After that in your `onActivityResult(...)` in your Activity you check for the ResultCode and trigger content refresh:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(..., String requestCode) {
     if(requestCode.equals(PHOTO_TAKEN) {
        adapter.refreshContent();
     }
}
```

And in your Adapter:

```
public class GalleryViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<IContentRefreshableFragment> mFragments;

    public void refreshContent() {
        for(IContentRefreshableFragment fragment : mFragments) {
            fragment.refreshContent();
        }
    }
}
```

So you can handle a bunch of `ViewPager` `Fragments` content refreshs without recreating the Fragments every time from any point in your context.
Also you could add Tags to your fragments and refresh just single ones if you modify the methods a little.

Answer (score 0):

Use getChildFragmentManager() in the constructor of your ViewPagerAdapter

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerGallery);
                GalleryViewPagerAdapter adapter = new GalleryViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    Fragment fragmentObject = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, i);
                    if (fragmentObject instanceof FragmentPhotos) {
                        FragmentPhotos fragment = (FragmentPhotos) fragmentObject;
                        if (fragment != null) {
                            ((FragmentPhotos) fragment).initGallery();
                            Log.e("", "Gallery called");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

There a issue with some tips in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55068